# What does "CPU performs an endless jump" mean?

Tags: cpu, boot, machine-code, sector

I was reading this: https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf
And I read on page 8 the following:

e9 fd ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

*

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa

The initial three bytes, in hexadecimal as 0xe9, 0xfd and 0xff, are actually
machine code instructions, as defined by the CPU manufacturer, to perform an
endless jump.

What do they mean by "perform an endless jump"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just a jump that jumps to itself. Nothing all that special.

In 16bit mode, `e9 fd ff` is an instance of `jmp rel16`. The offset `0xfffd` is -3, since jump offsets are "from the start of the next instruction", that's 3 bytes back from that first 00, so back to the `jmp`.

Comment: which is another way of saying that "endless jump" is a lame term.